# Error in Weblogic Server 11gR1(10.3.6) installation

Tags: java, spring, server, weblogic

I have tried to install Weblogic Server 11gR1(10.3.6) on deploying any application  I get the following error" **An internal error occurred during: "Starting Oracle WebLogic Server 11gR1 (10.3.6) at localhost
org.apache.xerces.dom.DeferredElementImpl.getTextContent()Ljava/lang/String**;"Can anyone provide a solution to solve this issue.I am using jdk 1.7 and Spring tool suite.

Comment: This question does not appear to be about programming within the scope defined in the help center.

Answer (score 0):

A step by step installation is given in this [tutorial: Installing and Configuring Oracle WebLogic Server](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36032_01/doc.722/e36041/ins_uim_setup_wls.htm). Hope it will help you.

### UPDATE1:

Eclipse works with WebLogic Server and then you start the server from the Eclipse project in the publishing stage

`An internal error occurred during: "Publishing to Oracle WebLogic Server 11gR1 (10.3.6) at localhost [base_domain] ..."`. If the error that I can.

This problem can be solved by installing download 'Oracle Coherence Tools for Juno' at the Eclipse Marketplace.

The reason is that the version you download the Juno eGovFrame implementation tools version 2.7.0 version based on Eclipse Juno win.
[image]

1. From the menu, select `'Help> Eclipse Marketplace ...'.` Eclipse Marketplace query window pops up  as a search for coherence.
   Among the search results by choosing to install the 'Oracle Coherence Tools for Juno'.

[image]

2. Installing a program list will be displayed in the selected state.

[image]

3. Consent to the Licenses and click the 'Finish' button.

[image]

4. The installation screen.

[image]

After the installation is complete you back to the WebLogic Server from the Eclipse publishing it will publish completed without error.

Comment: @user3449625 Please have a look in UPDATE1 portion.